# Bought code worked on JQuery 1.3.2 but not anymore on 1.5 What should I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version-control, gallery, jquery-events

About 6 months ago I bought a gallery photo popup code. It came with jQuery 1.3.2

It works fine with jQuery 1.4.1 too, but anything after that, at the moment of opening the photo, it does go into fade dark but does not open the big photo. I can edit a bit Javascript here or there but am not able to write code let alone fix this.

**My motivation for using JQuery 1.5** / 1.5.1  is that everything else works much faster with these new builds! I really would prefer to update to these version as opposed to the 1.3.2 that I bought.

I asked the original author but he has other things to do than custom update code for my request. Since I'm not here to complain, but to solve my issue, any help would be very appreciated.

**Question. Would it be legal** if I put the full Javascript contents temporarily in here so that my bought code would work again? After its solved I could remove the portions that were not causing the issue, that way this question and its answer are to the point and might help others using the same or similar lightbox gallery.

Comment: If we looked at your website we would be able to see the code, so by the nature of the web it is already public. So i can see no reason not to post it here. have you talked to the plugin creator about the problem?.

Comment: Thanks LongHairedSi! You are right, I have updated my question...

Comment: Depending on the license that the original developer developed the plug-in under (I'm assuming the JS is yours since you paid for it...), you could hire any developer to work out the bugs for you. Don't ask that here, but there are plenty of sites out there that will connect you with good JavaScript developers. That may be an avenue that you want to look at if you need additional help.

Comment: @JasCav, thanks for your advise: can you mention 1 or 2 good sites where I can hire an individual to fix my JavaScript issues? I will then try to delete my question here as you advised.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to leave this question. If the community didn't like it, they would have marked it for deletion. I was just saying don't try to hire developers via this site (that will get deleted). I have not used any of these sites, so I really can't make a recommendation, but a quick Google search could probably turn up quite a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I... Without seeing the code (and I don't know anything about legality, I'll leave that to someone else), I don't think there's much we can do to help you.

But, luckily jQuery has a list of which functions changed when moving between major versions. I hope this may be of some help to you:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/

You can probably safely skip all the "new in x!" stuff, and concentrate on changes.

The most likely culprit I can think of is the change in jQuery.param from version 1.3.x to 1.4

Look for jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional on this page:

- http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

Comment: Awesome link Athena +1 thanks will check it out (although i find this difficult to understand but worth trying). Ps I updated my question with the scripts and css included.